# Upload images and attachments from frontend form

Tags: php, attachments, media, uploads

I'm not very expert of wordpress and I'm trying to create a frontend form sending information to my php function through ajax. I'd need help about uploading images and files as attachments of the post.

My jQuery / Ajax is sending everything correctly to my php file. The only thing I don't understand is why images are uploaded and files aren't being in the same function?

My html inputs are relatively named:

- `name="moreimages"`
- `name="morefiles"`

I use this php code for both images and files

```
if ($_FILES)
    {
        // Get the upload images
        $images = $_FILES['moreimages'];
        foreach ($images['name'] as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($images['name'][$key])
            {
                $image = array(
                    'name' => $images['name'][$key],
                    'type' => $images['type'][$key],
                    'tmp_name' => $images['tmp_name'][$key],
                    'error' => $images['error'][$key],
                    'size' => $images['size'][$key]
                );
                $_FILES = array("moreimages" => $image);
                foreach ($_FILES as $image => $array)
                {
                    $newupload = project_images($image,$pid);
                }
            }
        }
        // Get the upload attachment files
        $files = $_FILES['morefiles'];
        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($files['name'][$key])
            {
                $file = array(
                    'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                    'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                    'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                    'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                );
                $_FILES = array("morefiles" => $file);
                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array)
                {
                    $uploadfile = project_file($file,$pid);
                }
            }
        }
    }

function project_images($file_handler, $pid)
    {
        if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        $image_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $pid );
        return $image_id;
    }
function project_file($file_handler, $pid)
    {
        if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        $file_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $pid );

        //here is the only difference where I update the post meta

        update_post_meta($file_id,'is_prj_file','1');
        return $file_id;
    }
```

I can't see the problem. Can you drive me maybe suggesting a similar question answered? Thanks.

Comment: What are the extensions of the files you're trying to upload?

Comment: For images: image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif | For files: .doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.ppt,.pptx. @TimMalone

Comment: Hmm those files should be ok, I think. Do they work if you upload them through the normal WP media library?

Comment: How can I discover which file are allowed and which not? Even if I upload simple .doc it doesn't seem working... @TwerkingN00b

Comment: Yes they work If I use the WP Dashboard. Eventually Is there another method I can try to achieve it? @TimMalone

Comment: Ok good, that clarifies that it's not a problem with your WP setup but more with this code. That's the first step in debugging this. You'll probably need to do a bit more debugging/provide a bit more information to help someone solve this, though - for example, are the files being uploaded but not going into the media library? Or are they not being uploaded at all? Are you getting any PHP errors?

Comment: Found it! Adding an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned in a comment how it's important to debug your code. Here's why:

The images are added first.
In the image adding section, you're running this line of code:

```
$_FILES = array("moreimages" => $image);
```

Then when you get to your routine that adds the files, you start with this:

```
$files = $_FILES['morefiles'];
```

Can you see what's wrong here? At this point, `$_FILES` *only* contains `"moreimages"` and nothing else, because you overwrote it earlier.

You could simply create a new variable rather than resetting `$_FILES` (eg. `$my_processed_images = array("moreimages" => $image);` and then `foreach ($my_processed_images...`), but there's a lot of other things that can be done to make this code more redundant and easier to follow too.

A quick point on debugging: `print_r()` is your friend. For example, if you're expecting a variable to be holding something, `print_r($_FILES)` so you can see if it really is. This will help avoid hours of head scratching :)

Comment: That's very helpful man! I come back to study now!!! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm very sorry to bother you again. I'm just processing all the informations you've provided me. What I've understood is that if I change `$_FILES` into some other variable I could differentiate arrays and avoid to overwrite them each other. But I think I'm missing something because even so I can't achieve it. It uploads only `$_FILES` ignoring something like `$my_processed_images = array("moreimages" => $image);`. Going crazy...

Comment: Did you change the `foreach` on the next line to refer to `$my_processed_images` as well? What are you going thru is some basic PHP, I would recommend looking online for a good PHP tutorial to brush up on some of this as you will find it much easier to code then :) If you keep getting stuck, consider posting some specific questions with the problems you are having on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

If you are not very familiar and want a plugin that can do all that for you using drag and drop, try WP-TYPES and their CRED plugin.

Just don't mind their support, it's really frustrating.

Comment: Thank you but I'd rather learn how to code it! I want understand and improve my knowledge. Thanks again.